# C++ is it possible to use a class variable as a default argument

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, default-arguments

I have a class for a tree as shown below:

```
class avl
{
   node *root;
public:
    avl(int data){
      root->data = data;
    }

    int get_height(node *head = root){  //error here

        if (head->right == head->left) return 0;
        int l = get_height(head->left);
        int r = get_height(head->right);

        if (l > r) return l+1;
        return r+1;
     }
}
```

Unsurprisingly this generates an error at the `get_height` definition. g++ complains it as an "invalid use of non-static data member". Can I amend this issue or should I resort to an inelegant use of a wrapper here. I'd appreciate if you can add some details to what the standard says about the cause of this error.

Comment: What's inelegant about a wrapper?

   `int get_height() { return get_height(root); }
   int get_height(node *head) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible. [Non-static class members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) can't be used as default arguments.

> Non-static class members are not allowed in default arguments (even if
>   they are not evaluated), except when used to form a pointer-to-member
>   or in a member access expression.
>
> ```
> int b;
> class X {
>   int a;
>   int mem1(int i = a); // error: non-static member cannot be used
>   int mem2(int i = b); // OK: lookup finds X::b, the static member
>   static int b;
> };
> ```

From the standard, [[dcl.fct.default]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct.default#9)

> A non-static member shall not appear in a default argument unless it
>   appears as the [*id-expression*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.id#nt:id-expression) of a class member access expression
>   ([[expr.ref]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ref)) or unless it is used to form a pointer to member
>   ([[expr.unary.op]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary.op)). [ *Example:* The declaration of `X​::​mem1()` in the
>   following example is ill-formed because no object is supplied for the
>   non-static member `X​::​a` used as an initializer.
>
> ```
> int b;
> class X {
>   int a;
>   int mem1(int i = a);              // error: non-static member a used as default argument
>   int mem2(int i = b);              // OK;  use X​::​b
>   static int b;
> };
> ```
>
> The declaration of `X​::​mem2()` is meaningful, however, since no object
>   is needed to access the `static` `member X​::​b`. Classes, objects, and
>   members are described in [[class]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class). — *end example* ]

As you said you can add an overloaded wrapper function like

```
int get_height(node *head) {
    ...
}
int get_height() {
    return get_height(this->root);
}
```